# GraphQLName annotation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql

I am creating a simple login app using spring boot with Kotlin + GraphQL. @GraphQLName("") is not working for me.

my graphql is

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
type Mutation{
    requestOTP(credential: String!,authType: String!): String
}
```

and in my kotlin

```
@Controller
class ResetPassword(
    @Autowired val userRepository: UserRepository
): GraphQLMutationResolver {
@GraphQLName("requestOTP")
fun reset(credential: String, authType: String): String{ 
//codes...
}
}
```

But It keep saying

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message:
 Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/web/servlet/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/web/servlet/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletConfiguration' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/web/servlet/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletConfiguration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/web/servlet/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/web/servlet/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/tools/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/tools/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverError: No method found as defined in schema <unknown>:44 with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment, class graphql.GraphQLContext] as the last argument), in priority order:   
 com.auth.test.presentation.ResetPassword.requestOTP(~credential, ~authType)
 com.auth.test.presentation.ResetPassword.getRequestOTP(~credential, ~authType)
```

If I rename `fun reset` to `fun requestOTP`, the code compile even I put `@GraphQLName("LOLnothingLOL")`
. Kindly explain me why I am getting this error and how to fix it. I don't want to use `requestOTP` directly to have more readability.

**Edit:**
I am not using pom.xml instead build.gradle
Here is my gradle file.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.6"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.21"
}

group = "com.dagger"
version = "0.0.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql")
    implementation("com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:14.1.0")
    runtimeOnly("com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:11.1.0")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    modules {
        module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging") {
            replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2", "Use Log4j2 instead of Logback")
        }
    }

    //jwt token
    implementation ("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")

    implementation("com.expedia.graphql:graphql-kotlin-schema-generator:1.3.4")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-core")
    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework:spring-webflux")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Can you please share pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand the issue.

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/tools/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/tools/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverError: No method found as defined in schema <unknown>:44 with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment, class graphql.GraphQLContext] as the last argument), in priority order:
```

In above error message if you notice last statement, issue is very clear.

```
nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverError: No method found as defined in schema <unknown>:44 with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment, class graphql.GraphQLContext] as the last argument), in priority order:
```

So the issue is, in your Controller class, Mutation method name is `reset()` but in GraphQl schema file method name is `requestOTP()`. Both should be same.

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
type Mutation{
    requestOTP(credential: String!,authType: String!): String
}
```

Also I can see you are using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql` dependency in your `build.gradle` file. This dependency is enough for GraphQL implementation with Spring Boot. Please remove other GraphQL related dependencies. They are creating confusion in Spring ECO system.

Also if you writing GraphQL schema file yourself then no need to use `@GraphQLName` annotation.